# TF Object Detection input type for exported model

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow-serving

TF Object Detection API creates an `export/Servo` folder for use with TF Serving. I'm trying to figure out how I should send an image when I have the server running. Anybody know what type(s) it expects? I could send a numpy array, jpeg bytes, jpeg encoded base64 string, etc.